# vfprintf crash on 32 bit linux

Tags: c, linux, crash

I see a crash when I try to print the below log on 32 bit linux. The same  log works fine in 64 bit linux.

```
printf("store [%s] PREG marker 0x%x RegID %u Session ID %u Indices %u.%u [%s.%d] StoreID %x L/T <%d - %d> \n",
                         store->name, info->ume_preg.marker, regid, sid,
                         info->ume_preg.transport_idx, info->ume_preg.topic_idx,
                         store->name, ntohs(info->ume_preg.resp_port), store_id,
                         client->src->repo->lead_sqn,
                         client->src->repo->trail_sqn);
```

Core Stack : -

```
#0  0x00870b9f in __strlen_ia32 () from /lib/libc.so.6
#1  0x0083b4df in vfprintf () from /lib/libc.so.6
#2  0x008609f0 in printf () from /lib/libc.so.6
```

If you see in the log I have two string (store->name and store->name, printing store name twice). I see the crash only when I add two string in the print along with the other arguments. If I have only string along with other argument I don't see the crash.

Note crash only on 32 bit linux.

I am not sure why strlen crashes only for 32 bit linux.

OS information :-

```
-bash-4.1$ uname -a
Linux  2.6.32-358.6.1.el6.i686 #1 SMP Tue Apr 23 18:13:20 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

libc:-

```
-bash-4.1$ /lib/libc-2.12.so
GNU C Library stable release version 2.12, by Roland McGrath et al.
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
Compiled by GNU CC version 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4).
Compiled on a Linux 2.6.32 system on 2013-02-21.
```

Did anyone have any experience on this?

Comment: It's crashing in `__strlen_ia32 () `, so i guess it's one of the `%s` parameters in your pattern that causes the crash. Can you check if store->name is a valid pointer to 0-terminated string `const char*` or a `char[]`?

Comment: Yeah I have checked that. if I print store name once then it prints fine. Even if I replace the store name with some string like "abc" and provide twice as argument then also it crashes.

Comment: it's maybe a bug in the glibc. Do you have this behavior with a newer linux, with newer glibc, too?

Comment: Just because the machine on which it crashes happens to be a 32 bit machine, there is not much of an indication that this is the cause. In fact, there is almost no indication at all in your post to find the problem. Please use a debugger and have a look at all the parameters that are passed in when it actually crashes.

Comment: Sorry I haven't tried updating glibc. But I don't see any bug on the same. Also if I write a simple main with print on similar arguments it doesn't crash. It only crash from my application.

Comment: I have checked the same on multiple 32 bit and 64 bit Linux machine and it crashes in all 32 bit machines. Also I have checked values of all those arguments and all looks fine. Note if I remove one store name string from the print the it will print without any issue. It crashes with I add a 2nd string to the argument list.

Comment: Your code could do some stack overwriting somewhere else and run on 64 bit architecture just by accident, e.g. different alignment or pointer size.

Comment: Guys after a lot of debugging I was just realized  "sid" on my printf statement is  lbm_uint64_t.

lbm_uint64_t sid .

I am printing the sidusing %u. Can it be a reason. Should I use PRId64 or anything else?

Comment: Thanks for everyone's help. The printf should have used PRId64  or %lld to print uint64. This was causing the crash.